# Common wire for furnace to thermostat

Tags: furnace

I have a blue wire being unused on both the furnace and thermostat. If I connect that blue wire on both ends will I have power?

Page one of the wiring diagram:

[image: diagram page 1]

Page two of the wiring diagram:

[image: diagram page 2]

What it looks like at the thermostat:

[image: wiring at t-stat]

How it looks at the furnace:

[image: wiring at furnace]

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: In future, use the [edit] link underneath your post to update it with extra information or to respond to comments. You won't be able to add any more answers here until you merge your accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You indeed should be able to connect the blue wire to the C terminals at the thermostat and furnace control board and have it all work without a hitch.